# Formatting the date and time that returns from created_at

Tags: php, twitter

I've been trying to display the status `created_at` time in users local time through the below API.

```
$content = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline', array('count' => 14));
```

**Response** (for readability i posted 2 fields from each result) :

```
[created_at] => Sun Dec 14 04:58:58 +0000 2014
[utc_offset] => 19800

[created_at] => Sun Dec 14 04:58:11 +0000 2014
[utc_offset] => -28800

[created_at] => Sun Dec 14 04:57:56 +0000 2014
[utc_offset] =>
```

In the above response, you can see in a result `utc_offset` is empty. So,

1. How should i get the current local time of user?
2. What's the default timezone that we receive in created_at?
3. How to convert the Twitter generated TimeDate to local users
   timezone?

Through my research,
i found that we can obtain the current users local time by

- Diving the `utc_offset` by 3600.
- Then adding those value to the created_at time.

But, what if in case if `utc_offset` field is empty?

Answer (score 1):

To answer question #2,  the default time zone is GMT (UTC).  Look at the format of the date/time string:

Sun Dec 14 04:58:58 +0000 2014

the +0000 means that the timezone is GMT.  GMT is always +0000.

To answer your other question:

If utc_offset is null, then that means the user has not set a time zone in their profile.  In that case, you will have to use 0 as the offset, and assume they are at GMT.  If they have geotagging turned on however, you might be able to deduce their location by the coordinates.  However I'm not sure if geotagging works with no timezone set up in a profile.

Comment: I finally decided to show the Time zone list to let the user select their timezone in-order to get the exact result.